# How to connect to SQL Server 2008 database at runtime in configuration file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 at runtime in a configuration file.

I'm only connect to SQL Server 2008 Express that built-in Visual Studio 2008.

Here is some code that I wrote

```
<add name="MyName" 
     connectionStrings="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|\Database\mydatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=true;User Instance=true;" />
```

That code is to connect to SQL Server 2008 Express database.

I want to know which code can connect real SQL Server 2008 database instead of SQL Server Express...

Please answer me if you know...
Always respects all of you...

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

It goes over the various ways  you can setup your connection strings. Your "typical" connection string (if there is such a thing) will probably look something like this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

But it really depends on how your SQL Server instance is configured and what kind of security you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm using AD authentication, I go with

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

If SQL server auth, I use

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```